# How to integrate multiple jQuery cdn calls in wordpress while using plugins?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, cdn, conflict

My word press site's first page uses multiple j query code and plugins which cause conflicts (I think) leading to acting some j query animations abnormal ex: my carousel.
Is there a way for integrating multiple j query Cdn calls for one, in Wordpress pages and make it central to easily use as how many j query plugins you want to use without any conflicts?
Or is the j query conflicts have different complicated story? as you know it is a WordPress page and it combines things together, resulting a crowded page full of codes which I have no ideas where did every call had been coming from (is it from the theme or a plugin).
and is there a way to prevent a plugin (visual composer page builder in this case) in certain pages?
please help me overcome this problem better. Actually, I'm a bit confused.
thanks.

Comment: Why are you making any CDN calls in the first place?

Comment: I didn't, its just what had been made originally from theme and plugins, I'm a bit novice to write a theme from scratch and I'm just edit and use plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in function.php to remove loading of particular plugin script and style sheet from home page.

```
/*disable loading plugin script to homepage*/

function wpa54064_inspect_scripts() 
{
global $wp_scripts;
if ( is_home() ) 
{
wp_dequeue_script('plugin-script-handle');
}    
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpa54064_inspect_scripts' ); 

/*disable loading plugin css to home page*/

add_action('wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles', 99999);

function my_deregister_styles() 
{
global $wp_styles;
if(is_home())
{
  wp_dequeue_style('plugin-css-handle');
  wp_deregister_style('plugin-css-handle');  
 }
}
```

where plugin-script-handle and plugin-css-handle can get by global $wp_scripts and global $wp_styles.

Comment: how to know the working name of the plugin? isn't there any more simple way to know the name of the plugin? without grabbing from the code?

Comment: You can check active plugin name through plugin handle.